# Is it a good way Referencing Nop.Web in a plugin to use View Models?

Tags: plugins, nopcommerce

I'm writing a plugin for NopCommerce and i can not decide if I should add Nop.Web to plugin project or just create same model which in Nop.Web.Models. What do you think?

Comment: Where do you want to use the existing model for?

Comment: I want to create a catalog plugin which shows 5 product for each sub catagory of a parent catagory. I used ProductOverviewModel which in Nop.Web.Models namespace. Should I create my own model or that's not any problem?

Comment: You should always create your own model when creating a plugin, this is because you then don't have to update the source code when nopcommerce updates, you then only have to install your plugin.